# Netty tmpNioBuf UnpooledDirectByteBuf

Tags: java, netty

When I read the source code of the `UnpooledDirectByteBuf`.java of Netty5, the "private ByteBuffer tmpNioBuf;" field makes me confused.
In the code of UnpooledDirectByteBuf.java like this:

```
private void getBytes(int index, byte[] dst, int dstIndex, int length,
        boolean internal) {
    ... ...
    if (internal) {
        tmpBuf = internalNioBuffer();
    } else {
        tmpBuf = buffer.duplicate();
    }
    tmpBuf.clear().position(index).limit(index + length);
    tmpBuf.get(dst, dstIndex, length);
}
```

We can see that, sometimes we can use the `internalNioBuffer()` method to get the "tmpNioBuf" as the tmpBuf by setting the "boolean internal" param "true",such as:`readBytes(byte[], int, int)`method and sometimes we use the "`buffer.duplicate()`" to get the tmpBuf.
Why did the author design it like this? 
Thanks!

Comment: Please give more information about the datatypes used.

Comment: My native language is not English,Maybe I don't understand you very well. I just want to know why `readBytes(byte[], int, int)` use the `private ByteBuffer tmpNioBuf;` and `ByteBuf getBytes(int index, byte[] dst, int dstIndex, int length)` use `buffer.duplicate()` to create new ByteBuffer?

Answer (score 0):

the `internalNioBuffer()` returns the same instance of `ByteBuffer` everytime where `buffer.duplicate()` will return duplicate which has separate limit and position.

As `duplicate()` will create a new `ByteBuffer` instance, we use `internalNioBuffer()` where possible to reduce object creation.